# getWriter() has already been called for this response

Tags: tomcat, httpresponse, spring-boot-3

Why can I only use response.getOutputStream() in a project, when I use response.getWriter(), it always throws exception, but I can use response.getWriter() in an old project, and after I used this outputStream, I can not close it, because if I close it, my controller can not response anything for me, I think this is to terrible!!!!!!

someone can answer my question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you please provide an [mcve] showing what you have tried, what works and what doesn't work so that people can run it and see what happens? I assume you are talking about `HttpServletResponse` but I don't know much more about your problem.